# How to make a blocking reqwest Client?

Tags: rust

Using code from https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/blocking/struct.ClientBuilder.html

```
use reqwest;
use std::time::Duration;

let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::builder()
    .timeout(Duration::from_secs(10))
    .build()?;
```

my Cargo.toml

```
reqwest = { version = "0.11.13", features = ["blocking", "json"] }
```

But I get error:

```
    error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a method that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> src/main.rs:27:13
   |
22 | /     fn new(&self) {
23 | |         //self.client = reqwest::blocking::Client::builder().build()?;
24 | |
25 | |         let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::builder()
26 | |     .timeout(Duration::from_secs(10))
27 | |     .build()?;
   | |             ^ cannot use the `?` operator in a method that returns `()`
28 | |     }
   | |_____- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, reqwest::Error>>` is not implemented for `()`
```

**Any ideas ?**

Comment: The error says _"the `?` operator can only be used in a method that returns `Result` or `Option`"_. Did you look into that?

Comment: If your method _does_ return an `Option` or a `Result`, you should include that in your question.

Comment: @PeterHall if I know what I am doing I would :-), did not understood that "method" is my method, my understanding was that there is something wrong with build()

Comment: If in doubt, always post the exact code that you ran, so someone else can copy+paste it to see the identicl error message themselves. If I Copy your code, I get an error about a missing main function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` operator in Rust takes a `Result<T, E>` value and propagates it to the caller if it's an error, unwrapping it otherwise.

You can think of

```
let client = something.builder()?;
```

as being roughly equivalent to

```
let client = match something.builder {
  Ok(inner_value) => {
    inner_value
  }
  Err(error) => {
    return Err(error);
  }
};
```

Now `build` *does* return a `Result` in your case, but your containing `new` function does *not*. So you're trying to return an error from a function that returns `()`. (Side note: A function called `new` should probably construct an object, not return `()`, but that's another issue)

So either have your function return `Result<..., E>` for some `E` compatible with the error type of `build` ("compatible" means "there exists an `impl From<E> for E1` from its type to your type") or handle the error in some other way.

If you have a default value you can return, you can do that with `unwrap_or` or `unwrap_or_else`

```
let client = something.builder().unwrap_or_else(|| some_appropriate_default());
```

or you can panic explicitly with `expect`.

```
let client = something.builder().expect("Something horrible happened! Plz debug!");
```

Comment: If anybody else is trying to make reqwest blocking client, it is not same as using "reqwest::blocking::get(url).unwrap();", so here are some code excepts.  client: reqwest::blocking::Client, reqwest::blocking::Client::builder().build().unwrap(), let resp = self.client.get(url).send().unwrap(); Did get 3x time performance.